Facing issue with Custom Function and Model in Tensor flow
I was implementing a Dehazenet model by using tensorflow where i had to create a Maxout and Brelu class and function as there is nothing built-in in tensorflow for them to use, later while trying to use my saved model i faced errors and exception
ERROR :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model/scripts/evaluate.py", line 69, in <module>
    metrics = evaluate_model(model_path, input_dir, target_dir)
  File "model/scripts/evaluate.py", line 49, in evaluate_model
    model = keras.models.load_model(model_path)
  File "D:\image-dehazing\env\lib\site-packages\keras\src\saving\saving_api.py", line 238, in load_model
    return legacy_sm_saving_lib.load_model(
  File "D:\image-dehazing\env\lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "D:\image-dehazing\env\lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\base_layer.py", line 870, in from_config
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Error when deserializing class 'Activation' using config={'name': 'activation', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'activation': {'module': 'builtins', 'class_name': 'function', 'config': 'brelu', 'registered_name': 'function'}}.

Exception encountered: Unknown activation function: 'function'. Please ensure you are using a `keras.utils.custom_object_scope` and that this object is included in the scope. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object for details. 

code:
import tensorflow as tf
from skimage.metrics import mean_squared_error, peak_signal_noise_ratio, structural_similarity
from preprocessing import load_dataset
from tensorflow import keras

# Clear all previously registered custom objects
keras.saving.get_custom_objects().clear()

# Define and register brelu as an activation function
@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable(package="MyActivations", name="brelu")
def brelu(x):
    return tf.maximum(0.0, tf.minimum(1.0, x))

# Define and register Maxout custom layer
@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable(package="MyLayers")
class Maxout(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_units, **kwargs):
        super(Maxout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.num_units = num_units

    def call(self, inputs):
        shape = tf.shape(inputs)
        num_channels = shape[-1]
        tf.debugging.assert_equal(num_channels % self.num_units, 0, message="Number of channels must be divisible by num_units")
        new_shape = tf.concat([shape[:-1], [self.num_units, num_channels // self.num_units]], axis=-1)
        output = tf.reduce_max(tf.reshape(inputs, new_shape), axis=-1)
        return output

    def get_config(self):
        config = super(Maxout, self).get_config()
        config.update({"num_units": self.num_units})
        return config

def evaluate_model(model_path, input_dir, target_dir, size=(256, 256)):
    """
    Evaluate the trained model on the test dataset.
    
    Args:
    - model_path (str): Path to the trained model file.
    - input_dir (str): Directory with input (hazed) images.
    - target_dir (str): Directory with target (dehazed) images.
    - size (tuple): Desired size for resizing the images.

    Returns:
    - dict: Evaluation metrics (MSE, PSNR, SSIM).
    """
    # Load the trained model with custom objects
    with keras.utils.custom_object_scope({'brelu': brelu, 'Maxout': Maxout}):
        model = keras.models.load_model(model_path)
    
    # Load and preprocess the dataset
    X, y_true = load_dataset(input_dir, target_dir, size)

    # Make predictions
    y_pred = model.predict(X)

    # Compute evaluation metrics
    mse = mean_squared_error(y_true.flatten(), y_pred.flatten())
    psnr = peak_signal_noise_ratio(y_true, y_pred)
    ssim = structural_similarity(y_true, y_pred, multichannel=True)

    return {'MSE': mse, 'PSNR': psnr, 'SSIM': ssim}

I tried using the documentation , tried the serialization function and gpt also but no solution worked. I only want that my loaded model work prefectly so i can integrate it with my frontend code

This sounds like you are using different versions of keras/tensorflow to save and load the model.

I am using tensor 2.13.0

The error you’re encountering suggests that TensorFlow/Keras is having trouble deserializing your custom activation function and layer. This is likely due to the fact that the model was saved with custom objects that aren't recognized when you attempt to load the model.
To resolve this issue, you need to ensure that TensorFlow/Keras can properly identify and deserialize these custom objects when loading the model.
